# Angular2 Global user object in every component

Tags: dependency-injection, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

Hy!
I am able to share Parent container's property via attribute directive and inputs, but it doesn't work if the child component is pulled in by `<router-outlet>`. Any advice how to share with every component?

Btw i get the global user with async call in the app.component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a service? Just write a service (let's call it UserService), attach it to the `AppComponent`s array of `viewProviders` (so it will only be created once for the application and is a singleton).

Assuming TypeScript, the `UserService` class must be decorated with `@Injectable()` so you can just auto wire it in any component and other service. Store your global user object in it as an instance variable. This is nice because you can handle your user object in one place now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was dumb.. i used a service to get the User Obj via async but didn't think about the service could store the object after get it once and only return the object itself. :)

Answer (score 4):

In this case use a shared service like explained in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

```
@Injectable()
export class User {
  ...
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [User],
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {}


@Component({
  selector: 'routed-comp',
  providers: [],
  ...
})
export class RoutedComponent {
  constructor(private user:User) {}

  /* use this.User here */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you too, i accepted @JoVer 's answer because he was faster. Both of you helped me to find the solution.